# Mimekit installing certificates upon verify

Tags: c#, smime, mimekit

I am using `MimeKit` to verify that an SMIME multipart signed message is signed by a specific entity. I have the public certificate for this entity. When calling `Verify(context)` on the `MultipartSigned` object, the certificate is being imported into the servers certificate list. What I want is that this errors if the certificate is not found. otherwise if a malicious user signs a file it would pass through, and what's worse I would end up with his certificate installed.

Is my reasoning flawed here?

This is the code I'm using.

```
var signed =(MultipartSigned)MimeEntity.Load(ParserOptions.Default,@"C:\mysignedfile.txt");

using (var context = new WindowsSecureMimeContext(StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    foreach (var signature in signed.Verify(context))// This install the certificate!
    {
        try
        {
            bool valid = signature.Verify();
        }
        catch (DigitalSignatureVerifyException)
        {
            throw;
            // There was an error verifying the signature.
        }                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the certificate in your certificate store does not mean that it is trusted, it just means that it is known.

That's all.

This allows you to later mark it as trusted and also allows your system to check for revocations.

Comment: Agreed. I ended up adding additional code to check whether the certificate is trusted. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing in my project. I want the signature verification to fail if the public key of the signing entity is either not installed or installed but not trusted. Did I understand correctly, that the signed message also contains the public key for verification so I cannot let the verification fail only because the certificate is not installed in my Windows certificate store?

Comment: Generally signed messages also contain the certificate, yes.